# looping in iMacro with condition | Solving Captcha if incorrect repeat

Tags: javascript, loops, captcha, imacros

I am trying to solve the captcha and go forward with the rest of the task but problem is if I get the wrong answer I can give back feedback if it was right or not but can't solve the captcha again right away, the page not go forward if the wrong captach, it eventually get back to start after the allocated time and timeouts but I want to loop the part of captcha solving area again. My code is working fine start to end if captcha answer is right even for days here is the code

```
SET apikey G9W API KEY GO HERE
SET !VAR1 NULL
SET !VAR2 NULL
SET !VAR3 NULL
SET !VAR4 NULL

'Step 1: Open WEBSITE
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=URL TO GO
WAIT SECONDS=10

URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,450)

'Step 2: Save Captcha ScreenShot
FILEDELETE NAME=d:\test.jpg
'SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=d:\ FILE=test.jpg
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:adcopy-puzzle-image CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
WAIT SECONDS=5

'Step 3: Send Captcha For Solving to 9kw
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:apikey CONTENT={{apikey}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:prio CONTENT=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:selfsolve CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:confirm CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:case-sensitive CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:source CONTENT=imacros
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:file-upload-01 CONTENT=d:\test.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 180
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:captchaid EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
'Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
SET !EXTRACT NULL
'Extract the characters that are recoginzed from the picture of captcha.
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:result EXTRACT=TXT
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAB CLOSE

'Step 4: Check the captcha answer (text or nothing like #EANF# = Extraction Anchor Not Found)
SET !VAR2 EVAL("if (\"{{!EXTRACT}}\" == \"#EANF#\") {var x = \"\";} else {var x = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\";} x;")
'Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Step 5: Fill the recognized characters to the verification box
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:adcopy_response CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 40
WAIT SECONDS=5
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=ID:subbmit
WAIT SECONDS=5

'Step 6: Check and send the captcha feedback back to the captcha service (OK:1, NotOK:2, EN: Right/False, DE: Richtig/Falsch)
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Wrong<SP>Captchas EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR3 EVAL("if (\"{{!EXTRACT}}\" == \"#EANF#\") {var x = \"1\";} else {var x = \"2\";} x;")
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 60
URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/index.cgi?source=imacros&action=usercaptchacorrectback&apikey={{apikey}}&correct={{!VAR3}}&id={{!VAR1}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
SET !VAR4 {{!VAR3}}

'Step 7 NEXT Tasks
```

I want to loop the code from Step 2 to Step 6 if !VAR3 have the value 2 which mean captcha is not ok but continue if it is 1 which means captcha is right, I tried to split the macro in 3 macros first one containing Step 1 second one containing Step 2 to 6 and third containing Step 7 and onward and try to call them in js script as follow

```
//Step 1 Open Website
iimPlay("test1.iim");

//STEP 2 to 6 Fill Captcha untill right

for(i=2;i<=1;i--)
{
iimSet("{{!VAR4}}",i);
iimPlay("test2.iim");
}

//STEP 7 Go About doing your thing
iimPlay("test3.iim");
```

But this usually play test 1 skip test 2 and test part 3 I tried putting all codes in the js file and try same thing there second part also skip, I want the value of !VAR3 or to controll the loop and repeat untill it have value 1

please help me loop this second part I know I can't do that in the iim file will have to use java and I not know the programming usually in DOS I can label thing and just point GOTO LABEL etc but here I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use iimGetLastExtract() for return values from your iimPlay.
See http://wiki.imacros.net/iimGetLastExtract()